# Javascript function not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

```
function getProfileInfo(profileURL) {
    $.get(
        profileURL,
        function(response) {
            console.log("HERE");
            var carBrandText = profileURL.toLowerCase().match(/(audi|Subaru|Lexus|Porsche|bmw|mazda|buick|toyota|kia|honda|hyundai|volvo|mini|mercedes|volkswagen|ford|lincoln|scion|acura|chevrolet|nissan|infiniti|gmc|cadillac|dodge|chrysler|rover|mitsubishi|jeep|fiat)/i);        
            if (carBrandText) {
                var getCarModelYear = response.match(/Model(\sYear)?.{0,10}(\d{2,4})/i);
                if (getCarModelYear) {
                     console.log("Year HERE");
                    $('#otherInfo').text('Other Information');
                    $('#otherInfoLinks').append('<li>Car Year: ' + getCarModelYear[2] + '</li>');
                }
                var getCarModelManufacturer = response.match(/Manufacturer.{0,10}(audi|Subaru|Lexus|Porsche|bmw|mazda|buick|toyota|kia|honda|hyundai|volvo|mini|mercedes|volkswagen|ford|lincoln|scion|acura|chevrolet|nissan|infiniti|gmc|cadillac|dodge|chrysler|rover|mitsubishi|jeep|fiat)/i);
                if (getCarModelManufacturer) {
                     console.log("Model HERE");
                    $('#otherInfo').text('Other Information');
                    $('#otherInfoLinks').append('<li>Car Manufacturer: ' + getCarModelManufacturer[1] + '</li>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, this function does not work on mobile devices. On desktops, I get the console log messages `HERE` and `Year HERE` and `Model HERE`, and the text is appended into `#otherInfoLinks`, while on Mobile Browsers, (Chrome for Android and Safari for iPhone), only the `HERE` appears in the console and nothing else. And the text is not appended into the certain areas.

Why would this be happening?

## **UPDATE**

```
                    var accountFindRegex = 'href\\=\\"([^\\"]*?(members?|profile|users?|players?).{0,15}' + nameToSearch + '.*?)\\"';
                    var regexVar = new RegExp(accountFindRegex, "i");
                    var currentWebsiteURL = searchResults.d.results[i].Url;
                    $.get(
                        currentWebsiteURL,
                        function(response) {
                            var profileLink = response.toLowerCase().match(regexVar);
                            if (profileLink) {
                                var checkBaseLink = profileLink[1].match(/(https?.*?\.\w{3}\/)/);
                                if (checkBaseLink) {
                                    if (document.getElementById("theirAccountsList").innerHTML.indexOf(checkBaseLink[1]) == -1) {
                                        $('#theirAccounts').text('Accounts');
                                        $('#theirAccountsList').append('<li><a href="' + profileLink[1] + '" target="_blank">' + checkBaseLink[1] + '</a></li>');
                                        getProfileInfo(profileLink[1]);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    var baseLink = currentWebsiteURL.match(/(https?.*?\.\w{3}\/)/);
                                    if (baseLink) {
                                        if (document.getElementById("theirAccountsList").innerHTML.indexOf(baseLink[1]) == -1) {
                                            $('#theirAccounts').text('Accounts');
                                            $('#theirAccountsList').append('<li><a href="' + baseLink[1] + profileLink[1] + '" target="_blank">' + baseLink[1] + '</a></li>');
                                            getProfileInfo(baseLink[1] + profileLink[1]);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                console.log(currentWebsiteURL + "  -test");
                            }

                        });
```

For some reason, `console.log(currentWebsiteURL + "  -test");` never displays the Mazda link, that means that for some reason, it doesn't match on Mobile yet it does on Desktop...?

Comment: I've removed [tag:html5] and [tag:jquery-mobile], they're irrelevant. ([tag:jquery] is also probably irrelevant, but it's useful to let people know that jQuery is okay in any solutions...)

Comment: Not seeing anything there that should be special on mobile devices. Rather than logging "HERE", I would suggest logging `profileURL` and `response`.

Comment: (This isn't the problem, but just a couple of things I noticed: If you're just checking for a match but not using the match result [such as `carBrandText`]. `regex.test(string)` is usually a better choice. And as your regexes have the `i` flag, no need for `profileURL.toLowerCase()`. Also recommend consistency [e.g., `audi` and `subaru` or `Audi` and `Subaru` but not `audi` and `Subaru`, but that's just a style thing given the ``i flag...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh wow. Thank you so much for all the suggestions! I didn't realize about the regex.text(string) so I'll implement that, and I don't think the issue is what i'm logging, cause it never even hits that part of the function

Comment: My point was that in the place where you *do* see `HERE` on mobile, log `profileURL` and `response` as clearly they're not what you're expecting in the regex.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, I thiiiiink I found the issue. I updated the OP

Comment: Is this a genuine website, or one of those mobile app wrapper things (Cordova/PhoneGap, ...)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Genuine website, it's just responsive is all. So it doesn't make sense to me that anything would be different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112261/discussion-between-ilovephp123-and-t-j-crowder).